# Can I search for an element from AJAX request without using REST module?

Tags: php, functional-testing, codeception

There's a table in my app which appears after receiving an AJAX request. I use `sendAjaxPostRequest()` and I want to grab text from it using `grabMultiple()` function, but codeception can't find the elements pointed by the xpath. I'm 100% sure the xpath is correct, because even on the _output html file I can find it using Chrome's console.

Another thing is I can find the text inside the table using `I->see("text")`.

I use PageObjectPattern, but to put it simple my code looks like:

```
$I->sendAjaxPostRequest($req-address);
$I->see('event to search');
$events = $I->grabMultiple("//a[contains(@href, '/event/')");
$I->assertContains('event to search', $events);
```

and the response contains:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8">
  <h3 class="event_name_published">
    <a href="/event/event-to-search">event to search</a>
  </h3>
</div>
```

The `see('event to search')` function passes while `grabMultiple` gives me

> Element that matches CSS or XPath or Regex element with
>   '//a[contains(@href, '/event/')' was not found.

Do you know a way to locate an element using xpath after performing an AJAX request?

Comment: What is the response you get from the ajax call. And show the code what you have tried.

Comment: + make sure that elements you are searching are visible. $I->see() looks for  visible elements only.

Comment: I'm sure they are. In the _output folder I get the html file with the view in which the test failed and I can see this element and also locate it with chrome's console using its xpath

Comment: Try to wait several seconds (e.g. `$I->wait(2000)`) after `sendAajxPostRequest()`. There are chanses that `$I->see()` called just before new elements inserted into page after ajax call or became visible.

Comment: I can't use `$I->wait()` in functional tests since it requires the WebDriver module available for acceptance tests.